# Python - Simplificar uso de try - except

Tags: python, python-3.x, excepciones

Tengo estas funciones en Python:

```
def CrearCarpeta (Nombre):
    try:
        os.mkdir (Nombre)
        return True
    except: return False

def BorrarCarpeta (Nombre):
    try:
        os.rmdir (Nombre)
        HacerAlgoMas ()
        return True
    except: return False
```

Mi objetivo es devolver False en caso de capturar algún error en mis funciones, de lo contrario devuelve True. Pero me gustaría evitar el uso de tantos try - except para hacer esto. Se me ocurre el uso de los decoradores, pero no se como usarlos. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, en lo personal no me parece buena idea poner mucho código dentro de un try y si ocurre un error hacer que la función retorne False. Eso te dificultará hayar los errores.

Sin embargo, te daré una respuesta de todos modos.

---

#### Solución

Como dices, se pueden usar decoradores. Al principio son muy dificiles de entender, pero una vez que te acostumbas, ya les agarras la mano.

En este caso vamos a usar decoradores estaticos, es decir aquellos que no necesitas llamarlos (poner parentesis a la derecha) para que funcionen.

```
def try_except(callback):
    def nuevo_callback(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            callback(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            return False

        return True

    return nuevo_callback

@try_except
def hola_mundo():
    return "hola mundo"

@try_except
def raise_error():
    raise

print(hola_mundo())
print(raise_error())
```

Produce:

```
True
False
```

#### Explicación

¿Pero que rayos es lo que hay más arriba? Es la función que actuará de decorador estatico. Vamos a explicarla por partes.

Primero que nada, hay que saber que en caso de un decorador estatico sobre una función:

```
@try_except
def hola_mundo():
    return "hola mundo"
```

Es equivalente a:

```
def hola_mundo():
    return "hola mundo"

hola_mundo = try_except(hola_mundo)
```

Como podrás notar, un decorador estatico (y también dinamico) tiene que devolver el valor a reemplazar la función original (que puede o no ser una función).

Sabiendo esto, ya podemos ver por partes la función decoradora.

```
def try_except(callback):
```

Esto es la función decoradora, lo que colocas despues del @. Recibe un solo argumento, que es la función original.

```
def nuevo_callback(*args, **kwargs):
```

Esta es la función por la que vamos a reemplazar a la original. Puede recibir cualquier numero y tipo de argumentos. Esto se debe a que despues necesitamos pasar estos argumentos a la función original.

```
return nuevo_callback
```

Una vez creada la función de reemplazo, la devolvemos para que Python se encargue de hacer el reemplazo.

---

Por supuesto, puedes pasarle argumentos a los decoradores, pero esos pasarían a ser decoradores dinamicos y merecerían una explicación diferente (que se iría demasiado del tema original de la pregunta). Te recomiendo leer este tutorial: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/decoradores/

Comment: Todo perfecto. Incluso he comprendido en gran medida como funcionan los decoradores. Gracias. Ya voté y marqué esta respuesta.

Comment: Por cierto se q es una mala idea incluir muchas lineas dentro de un try except :). Pero seria perfecta por ejemplo para llamar a os.mkdir. Si se crea la carpeta, devuelve None. De lo contrario se lanza un error q puede ser de permisos, porq ya existe la carpeta, etc. Al decorarla, la funcion cambia a: si se crea, devuelve True, y si no devuelve False.

Comment: Se pueden manejar como condicionales y no existe el riesgo de q el programa se detenga por una excepción.

Comment: No digo que quites por completo el try-except, pero que envuelvas solo lo necesario en el try. Por ejemplo en tu función borrar_carpeta, solo necesitas que esté dentro os.rmdir, no todo el código. Además, puedes capturar un tipo de error especifico en lugar de todos. Por cierto, me alegro de que te haya servido c: